# apply style to CSS classes with different numbers

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't know how to apply style to multiple classes with names
.field-img-gallery-0,
.field-img-gallery-1,
.field-img-gallery-2... etc
of course i can write it 50 times, but that's just stupid. can i somehow apply style to all this classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most concise way to do this is with a `substring` selector on the class attribute, although this won't work for some older browsers:

```
[class^="field-img-gallery-"] { /* CSS formatting code **/ }
```

The aboce snippet applies the css formatting to all elements that have a class that starts with `field-img-gallery-`

Comment: Actually selector is much more stricter than my solution, I used `element[class *= "field-img-gallery"]` I will delete my answer :)

Comment: A class *attribute* that starts with `field-img-gallery-`, as opposed to a class name, to be clear.

Comment: @BoltClock yep it would match against the whole value of the class attribute rather than the individual classnames that make up the attribute value.

Comment: i managed to make it with nth-child(odd) and (even) with parent div class. but that's only because i have only 2 fields in each parent class

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster for the browser to render CSS if you declared a general class for your fields and define styles for that particular class:

**.field-img-gallery** .field-img-gallery-0,

**.field-img-gallery** .field-img-gallery-1,

**.field-img-gallery** .field-img-gallery-2...